# SMTP in PHP config

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail

What is bad in this config?

```
// smtp hostname of your server, you can use localhost if
// it is the same server.
define ("MAIL_HOST", "smtp.gmail.com");

// SMTP username of your server, it is the same like
// PASSWORD if you use the same server
define ("SMTP_USER","fname.sname15@gmail.com");

// SMTP password of your server, it is the same like
// PASSWORD if you use the same server
define ("SMTP_PASSWORD","lololololo");
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong on those lines ;)

Comment: What's the error which makes you think theres something wrong in those lines?